# How to pass confirmation to a command line?

Tags: command-line

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

> After this operation, 21.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
>   Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

Can I set the confirmation value `Y` as option/argument to the command?
e.g.,  `sudo apt-get install git -y`

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/l41lUJ1YoZB1lHVPG/giphy.gif

Answer (score 1):

You can, but be warned that the prompt is there to protect you - do not bypass it lightly.

From `man apt-get`:

```
   -y, --yes, --assume-yes
       Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
       run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
       changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
       package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
       abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
```

Comment: Then is `sudo apt-get install git -y` right?

Comment: The man page (`man apt-get`) says `apt-get -y install git`.

Comment: You can put the `-y` wherever you want, as long as it’s after `apt-get`: `apt-get -y install git` = ``apt-get install -y git` = `apt-get install git -y`